# Issue with importError: no module named BaseHTTPServer

Tags: python-2.7, webserver, vagrant

Learning Python 2.7 and trying to run it on Vagrant.

Steps taken:
Vagrant up
Vagrant ssh
Run command python webserver.py

Issue when I run this command, it gives out an ImportError: No module named BaseHTTPServer.  Is this problem related to pg_config.sh?  Thank you in advance for helping me understand.

I have checked my python 2.7 directory.  BaseHTTPServer.py seems to be there.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, BaseHTTPServer



class WebServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

def do_Get(self):
    if self.path.endswith("/hello"):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_header()
        message = ""
        message += "<html><body>Hello!</body></html>"
        self.wfile.write(message)
        print message
        return
    else:
        self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)


def main():
try:
    port = 8080
    server = HTTPServer(('', port), WebServerHandler)
    print "Web Server running on port %s" % port
    server.serveforever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print " ^C entered, stopping web server...."
    server.socket.close()

if _name_ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You may consider switching to python 3.x. This is the updated version of your code in Python 3.7.2. Notice in the code below that the `BaseHTTPServer` module is changed to `http.server` in python3  [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class WebServerHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path.endswith("/hello"):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            message = ""
            message += "<html><body>Hello!</body></html>"
            self.wfile.write(message)
            print (message)
            return
        else:
            self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)


def main():
    try:
        port = 8080
        server = HTTPServer(('', port), WebServerHandler)
        print ("Web Server running on port %s" % port)
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print (" ^C entered, stopping web server....")
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can follow the link I provided above to read more from the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the python you are running/testing from the command line is the same python that your script is running?

i.e. BaseHTTPServer might be present in one install, but not the other.

For example, on my machine:

```
$ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

Is your "python" (in the command line you specified) the same as "python2.7"?

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import BaseHTTPServer
>>> BaseHTTPServer
<module 'BaseHTTPServer' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.pyc'>
```

Try a module that does exist to ensure the path is what you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler A.  running 'which python' gave me /usr/bin/python2.7.6. You are right.  It's not in the same command line as the "python 2.7.6".  Now I have to figure out my next step.

Answer (score 1):

In python earlier than v3 you need to run http server as

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8069
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pycharm, change the interpreter to Python 2.7 from the latest version.
If the project Interpreter is not present you can also add one by specifying the python 2.7 install path.

[image]